# Strange intuition about split infinitives

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, infinitives, to-infinitive

I recently encountered a sentence in a story that has got me to thinking:

> He at least had class enough not to leer.

The sentence as-is seems fine, although I would usually use a word order of "enough class", but if I make that change The non-split infinitive "not to leer" then strikes me as odd:

> He at least had enough class not to leer.

If I swap "class" and "enough" and also split the infinitive, it again seems fine:

> He at least had enough class to not leer.

And to complete the set, if I split the infinitive but leave "class enough" alone it again strikes me as very slightly odd:

> He at least had class enough to not leer.

I am simply curious if there is some more formal explanation backing my intuition regarding the two forms that are okay and the pair that are somewhat odd. Is it simply that "not to leer" is slightly more formal, thus needing to be paired with the slightly more formal "class enough" in order to not be jarring?

Comment: Putting ***enough*** after the word it modifies is a literary/poetic device.  [To His Coy Mistress](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44688/to-his-coy-mistress) by Andrew Marvell (1681) - *Had we but **world enough** and time, / This coyness, lady, were no crime.* There's no particularly strong preference for where exactly to position ***not*** in relation to its target. The position of ***at least*** can lead to ambiguity sometimes, but that's usually hypothetical rather than *real* ambiguity.

Comment: As FumbleFingers says, _class enough_ is literary, whereas _to not leer_ tends not to be literary. Your preference seems to be for combinations that are both literary, or both everyday.